# How can I find all the files whose name starts with "tty" in the /dev directory with all the file informations?

Tags: tty

How do I find all the files whose name starts with `tty` in the `/dev` directory?

Answer (score 1):

Open a console and type this:

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

The `*` expands to any pattern, including the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

All `/dev/tty*` files are character special files.

You can use `find`:

```
find /dev -type c -name 'tty*'
```

Or in `zsh`:

```
print -l /dev/tty*(%c)
```